# JS requestAnimationFrame blink on given Hertz

Tags: javascript

I have the below code blinking a canvas on a given interval, how could I make it blink on a given Hz (times per second)

```js
var startTime;
var interval;
var index = 0;
var colors = ['black', 'white'];
var id = null;

function animate(time) {
  id = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  if (!startTime) { startTime = time; }
  var elapsed = time - startTime;
  if (elapsed > interval) {
    startTime = time;
    canvas.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    if (++index > colors.length) { index = 0; }
  }
}

function startBlink() {
  interval = parseFloat(document.getElementById('freqBlink').value);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- frequency unit is Hertz (seconds^-1)
- interval unit is milliseconds

then:

```
interval = 1000 / frequency
```